# Cacti - central server to check status

Tags: monitoring, cacti

Hey is there a way to setup one server for cacti and having all the other servers send their data to it? I would have thought, that the poller sends all the info to the central server including the rdd files etc.. is there a way to do this?

Is there maybe a simple simular tool to do this if cacti does not have that capability? I would like to check CPU load, Disk space, RAM usage, Process number, logged in users... nice to have would be ping, disk i/o

I would love a simple setup and client I can run on all my debian machines...

Comment: Are you asking about having other CACTI servers forward their data to a central cacti server?

Comment: @Zypher - it looks like that's what he's describing, but I think he's using the wrong wording and what he actually means is a single cacti server that monitors multiple servers. It seems to me that he thinks he needs to install cacti on each server to monitor itself and then somehow collect those on a central server - which is not the way to go (if it's even possible.)

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, it's called SNMP, and it should be how Cacti works out-of-the-box. Have you read the Cacti docs? It should explain how to set up SNMP polling - the monitoring server asks, the monitored servers do not send*.

*unless you configure SNMP traps, syslog, or other complexities.

Answer (score 2):

I have no experience with Cacti, but I used **Munin** before for this kind of monitoring. There are Debian packages for it in the standard Debian repositories. On the central server that collects the data, you need to install the package "munin", and on the nodes that you would like to monitor, you install "munin-node". I have used it before and it is very very simple to setup. There are several plugins included to monitor stuff, and I think that all the things that you asked for are supported with the standard plugins. (Search the debian repository for munin to find packages with extra plugins.)

[Munin](http://munin.projects.linpro.no/)

Comment: +1 for using munin for this kind of thing - so much easier to set up and maintain than any other solution I've tried.

Answer (score 0):

I would say without doubt, switch to [Zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/), it will fit your needs.

Comment: I tried it and the setup was not as easy as I would like it to be.. I never got the same server to talk to it's client..

Comment: Your question is unclear , by the way i've compiled zabbix on numerous platforms without running into problems, you can make distributed monitoring using nodes or proxies.